# React Native: API Function making multiple calls to API server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using the Yelp API and Expo Location in React Native. My function for calling the API and getting the location is making 3 calls on each load. I'm guessing it's because my state is changing and causing the function to run again, but I can't seem to get it to stop.

Any thoughts on the hook below?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import yelp from '../api/yelp';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({});
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  const searchAPI = async (defaultTerm) => {
    try {
      const response = await yelp.get('/search', {
        params: {
          limit: 50,
          term: defaultTerm,
          latitude: location.coords.latitude,
          longitude: location.coords.longitude,
          radius: 4000,
        },
      });
      setResults(response.data.businesses);
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage('Something went wrong ');
    }
  };

  console.log(`latitude: ${location.coords.latitude}`);
  console.log(`longitude: ${location.coords.longitude}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    searchAPI('');
  }, []);

  return [searchAPI, results, errorMessage];
};
```

The hook is being used here:

```js
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
const [searchAPI, results, errorMessage] = useResults();
    
const filterResultsByPrice = (price) => {
    return results.filter(result => {
        return result.price === price;
    });
};
    
return (
    <View style={styles.resultsContainerStyle}>
      <SearchBar 
        searchTerm={searchTerm} 
        onSearchTermChange={setSearchTerm} 
        onSearchTermSubmit={() => searchAPI(searchTerm)}
    />
  )
...
```

Comment: How are you using the hook?

Comment: I edited my post to include how it's being used.

Comment: Try moving the `searchAPI` call to the inside of the first `useEffect`, to the end of the asynchronous function

Comment: I don't understand how that would work. I need to be able to return the `searchAPI` function from my default export to access it in the search. Can you provide a more clear description of what you mean? Thanks!